# application installation in Ubuntu Linux 16.04

Tags: software-installation

Every time am tryna install an application on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 it isn't installed, instead popup message appear which says 'Unsupported operating system!' and 'Please upgrade to Windows 7 with Service Pack 1 or later.' although I have installed wine. PLEASE HELP

Comment: Hello and welcome to ask Ubuntu. Your question is a bit ambiguous. Wine is not a perfect replacement for Windows. If you have problems installing particular Windows applications you should ask questions about the specific apps as the answers will differ. Generally it is a good idea to explore the native application alternatives.